# Optimizing "tab" code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I've implemented a "tab" control that switches between two different tabs, pretty self explanatory.  Here's the relevant code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="tabs margin-r">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab">Tab 2</div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var tabs = {

  init: function() {
    // Initialize cookie
    if(readCookie("tab_cookie")==null) {
      $("#tab-1").addClass("current-tab");
    } else {
      $("#" + readCookie("tab_cookie")).addClass("current-tab");
    }
    // Handle click event
    $(".tab").click(tabs.switchTabs);
  },

  switchTabs: function() {
    $(this).siblings(".tab").removeClass("current-tab");
    $(this).addClass("current-tab");
    createCookie("tab_cookie", $(this).attr("id"));
  }
};

$(document).ready(tabs.init);
```

I'm looking to optimize this code, and provide support for multiple tabs to be on the same page.  Obviously, the use of `id`s here makes multiple tabs difficult, so I'm looking to change that implementation.  Any ideas, best practices, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**instead of using `id` you can use `data` for example:**

`<div data-tab="1" class="tab"></div>`

and that way you can access this using jQuery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$(this).data('tab'); // returns string: 1

// Get tab id and defaults to 1 if null
var tab_id = readCookie("tab_cookie") || 1;

// Set current tab
$('[data-tab=' + tab_id + ']', '.tabs').addClass('current');
```

---

**instead of attaching a listener to each tab. You can [delegate events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) by attaching the listener to the parent:**

```
$('.tabs').on('click', '.tab', tabs.switchTabs);
```

This will also give you the benefit if you even want to add more tabs using ajax after the DOM was already created.

---

**No need to use `siblings()` if there is only one tab set in page**

You can write this:

```
$(this).siblings(".tab").removeClass("current-tab");
$(this).addClass("current-tab");
```

like that:

```
$('.current-tab').removeClass('current-tab');
$(this).addClass("current-tab");
```

if you still need to use `siblings()` you can still use `$(this).siblings('current-tab')` to select only the tabs that needs to be changed, rather than all of them.

Comment: What if I have two separate tab controls?  Do I still not have to use siblings?

Comment: You are right. You will need to. I updated the answer :)

Comment: Okay cool.  I accepted this answer because it used a ton of stuff that I didn't really understand and optimized my code.  Thanks.

I added a second tab control to my code, and I'm working now to make sure that they both work fine separately.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are going to have loading issues, because if you are talking narrowing the html files into one html file you are going to have to consider minifying the html or other. However, about two years ago I tried to do what you are doing now, and it became a big mess. I came to the conclusion that it is best to run each individual page within the tabs as php sessions so if you switch tabs the other session would close from the tab you switched from. But for what you are specifying, you could list the tabs as variables, and go from there

Comment: I don't really understand your answer... my question is more about how to optimize only the above code, I'm not worrying about sessions or the switching of the actual pages yet.

Comment: `} else {
      $("#" + readCookie("tab_cookie")).addClass("current-tab");`        list the other tabs.